# Field email not updating in MySQL table (using PDO)

Tags: php, mysql, sql, pdo

I have a query running on a site that updates a user's profile. It updates every field **but** the *email* field as it should. Actually it's not doing anything at all with the email field.

I define my $email variable as such:

```
$email = str_replace(" ", "", trim($_POST['email']));
```

And then I use my database wrapper to update it:

```
MySQL::do_query(
    $db, 
    "UPDATE customer 
    SET 
        email=?,
        firstname=?, 
        surname=?, 
        phonenumber=?, 
        street_address=?, 
        postcode=?, 
        city=?, 
        extra_2=?,
        ssn=?,
        password=?
    WHERE customer_id=? 
    AND password=?", 
    array($email, $firstname, $surname, $phone, $address, $zip, $city, $extra_2, $ssn, StringConverter::generate_hash($email, $_POST['pw']), $customer, StringConverter::generate_hash($email, $_POST['pw']))
);
```

But, then to the problem, it doesn't update the email field. Every other field it updates just fine. I've tried running a separate query updating **just** the email, that doesn't work either.

It works fine when inserting, just not updating. And by this point I have no idea what could be wrong. And the $email variable holds the correct email address, although the query seems to ignore it. Any ideas?

Comment: can we see the structure of your table ?

Comment: I suggest you start by printing the resulting SQL right before you send it off to mysql. Perhaps you're missing quotes or the field is not placed in the right spot?

Comment: @WouterSimons The SQL looks right, PDO handles that, quotes in the right places and arguments in the right places.  
  
@Tsadiq: http://pastebin.com/f5aVXbjm

Comment: Well, you have to post sources of your wrapper to investigate.

Comment: My wrapper does the following: prepare($query); And then: execute($values); And on success, return results, otherwise echo error message and return false. There's really nothing more to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried updating multiple things along with the email? I'm guessing not, because I think if you change the email, then the entire update will not perform correctly... This is because you use `$email` in `StringConverter::generate_hash($email, $_POST['pw'])`, but if the email is changed, then the row won't meet the password check in the where clause.

Comment: Ah, obviously, I even had a variable storing the old email for that purpose. Thanks a bunch!